# What are the white grids at 9.6953038715817,98.576672019046 in Google Maps?

Tags: remote-sensing, land-classification

A friend asked me to help interpret the white grids at 9.6953038715817,98.576672019046 in Google Maps. In satellite image the grids are connected to rivers flowing into the Andaman sea. Most of the rivers are also covered with snow-white material. I guess the grids are for polluted water treatment. But these grids seem to lack patterns of water treatment plants.

Can anyone help interpret these grids? Clues are also appreciated!

Comment: Can you attach an image.  All I see is clouds.

Comment: he means the ponds to the west I think.

Answer (score 5):

Salt is a strong guess but they are a little far from the coast and a little small for salt ponds but they certainly could be salt ponds.

They are more likely in my opinion abandoned shrimp aquaculture ponds. This better fits the location and the size. Thailand is a major shrimp exporter. I have quite some experience delineating these ponds and these fit all the shrimp criteria but not salt.

See http://rsmas.miami.edu/bms/ the feature article by Hamilton at the top.

Actually looking at the picture of the entire region I can state almost certainly (but not 100%) they are aquaculture and most likely shrimp (https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=9.704489,98.578606&spn=0.096616,0.154324&t=m&z=13&lci=com.panoramio.all)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the girds just to the west of that point, my guess is [salt production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_evaporation_pond).  I don't know why the river water appears so white, maybe because of the high salt content of the water and low water levels?

Answer (score 0):

Salt production is a reasonable guess, but I think may just a weird image. It appears to me an issue with the light returning from that area (choppy sea maybe?) overloaded the sensors from what they are used to, and the color comes out way brighter than it should. It could also be slight cloud coverage and the sea combining to make a weird color. Either way it appears to not be a salt content thing.

If you actually look at it on the map view, it appears at plain water, and they are all over the place there. If you look at some of the northern ones (that are not taken in the same image) they are not nearly as white. There is also an agricultural school to the northeast which has the same (but smaller) pools of water all around it. They look to be more like fish farms actually.

Although I had to go quite a ways away from there to find this I think [here](http://www.panoramio.com/map/#lt=8.024731&ln=98.877547&z=-1&k=1&a=1&tab=1&pl=all) is a good example of the same stuff, with pictures that say its a fish farm.

This also goes along with [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranong_Province) which says this province's main industry is fishing and white clay mining. There is some potential for this to be pits where they dug out clay maybe? Could explain the color.

Edit: Apprently I am slow, @Stu beat me to it on the fishing side.